# Rails default parems for id set to new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a 404 error on my RoR app and i found that it was because one of the method in the controller, which should only triggers when the record is not new, triggered when the record is new.

I do by that checking if the id of that record nil in my controller.

```
before_action :create_record, if: proc { not params[:id].nil? }
```

I was confused by it was triggered so i went head and checked my front-end network, which show following:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"format"=>"json", "id"=>"new"}   <----Set to new by default
```

My completely controller looks like this:

```
class Api::MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :create_recotrd, if: proc { not params[:id].nil? }

  def show
  end

  def index
    @my_model = MyModel.all
  end


  def create
    @my_model = MyModel.new(my_model_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_model.save
        format.json { render json: @my_model, status: :created}
      else
        format.json { render json: @my_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @my_model = MyModel.update
  end

  private
    def create_record
      @my_model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
    end

    def my_model_params
      params.require(:my_model).permit(
        :city,
        :state,
        :county,
        :zip,
        :telephone,
        :email,
      )
    end
end
```

I cant seem to find out why the id in the parameters is set to "`new`" instead of "`nil`".

I tried in the console by doing `MyModel.new`, the default id was nil, but then when i do the `GET` request, the id was set to "new"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really weird approach to set a new record. I think the problem lies in your routes. You are probably trying to access `yoursite.com/your_model/new` and your routes are configured to look for

`get "your_model/:id" => "your_controller#show"`

You are probably missing

`get "your_model/new" => "your_controller#new"`

So when you try to visit `your_model/new` the routes map the "new" as the :id param in your url.

I don't see a `new` action in your controller as well. You should read up on basic resource set up for rails here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Comment: you are on the right track, it was the combination of router and controller issue, thanks.